# MySQL - Replacing Portion of String Based on Rows

Tags: mysql

So I've got a table. To simplify, I'll say it has `name` and `category` columns.

Some examples:

```
name            category
Juice: Apple    3
Beer: Miller    4   
Cat Food        9
Juice           0
Beer: Molson    4
Juice: Orange   3
Dog Food        9
Beer            0
```

What I would like to do is format a query that will find all `category = 0`, and then remove those names followed by a colon from other results, if they contain them. See below:

```
name            category
Apple           3    <- Instead of Juice: Apple
Miller          4    <- Instead of Beer: Miller
Cat Food        9
Juice           0
Molson          4    <- Instead of Beer: Molson
Orange          3    <- Instead of Juice: Orange
Dog Food        9
Beer            0
```

Is this possible?

Thank you!

**Edit**:
I have found that the following works - is it a bad approach?

```
SELECT
    category,
    REGEXP_REPLACE(
        name,
        CONCAT( '(', ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(  name SEPARATOR '|' ) FROM items WHERE category = 0 ), '): ' ),
        ''
    ) AS name
FROM
    tablename;
```

Comment: You could use `locate` and `substr` assuming the only case of `:` would be the one you want to remove.

Comment: Hopefully this is an over-simplification, and you do in fact a PRIMARY KEY

Comment: @Strawberry - Yes, this is very over-simplified.

Answer (score 0):

Use a self `LEFT` join of the table and a `CASE` expression:

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN t2.name IS NULL THEN t1.name
         ELSE SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.name, ': ', -1)
       END name,
       t1.category
FROM tablename t1 LEFT JOIN tablename t2
ON t1.name LIKE CONCAT(t2.name, ':%') AND t2.category = 0
```

Or with EXISTS:

```
SELECT CASE 
         WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM tablename t2 WHERE t1.name LIKE CONCAT(t2.name, ':%') AND t2.category = 0)
           THEN SUBSTRING_INDEX(t1.name, ': ', -1)
         ELSE t1.name
       END name,
       t1.category
FROM tablename t1
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=77b10b9ed9efe63fef446f0a9e44eb34).
Results:

```
> name     | category
> :------- | -------:
> Apple    |        3
> Miller   |        4
> Cat Food |        9
> Juice    |        0
> Molson   |        4
> Orange   |        3
> Dog Food |        9
> Beer     |        0
```

Comment: Both work very well, however performance takes a pretty big hit. I've edited my question with a possibility. How does it look?

Comment: @Stev Well, presumably you're only going to do it once

Comment: @Stev REGEXP_REPLACE() with aggregation for every row of the table? I would choose it only after testing every other option and found it to be better.

Comment: @forpas - It is significantly faster. However, I do run the risk of exceeding the GROUP_CONCAT length limit down the line so it's not exactly built to scale.

Comment: @forpas - To add, it would only be doing REGEXP_REPLACE on the rows that match my WHERE clause - which is typically 15-20.

Comment: @Stev no. It applies aggregation and regex to all the rows of the table. It does the replacement to only15-20 rows.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not misunderstanding, wouldn't something like this work?

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING_INDEX(tablename.name, ': ', -1) as name,
    `tablename`.`category`
FROM
    `tablename`
```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ca49683d66f583f7e8f1cb09787f06c6)

Comment: The requirement is: "find all category = 0, and then remove those names followed by a colon from other results, if they contain them".